# Problem launching WEBrick in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I need some help here. Whats it's problem when trying to launch WEBrick?

So I type in "rails server" into terminal to launch the WEBrick server and it spits out the response below.

Thanks for all the help!

```
david$ rails server
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/daviddiliberto/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Comment: Seeing your `Gemfile` and `database.yml` would help :)

Comment: Guys I am still having problems. mysql is located here: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`

Comment: how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install MySQL on your machine. You can get it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/).

After that, you need to have:

```
gem 'mysql'
```

In your Gemfile.

Comment: I believe that he's missing the actual mysql not the mysql gem

Comment: I have that, in my first line of the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes i am on OSX. I have installed the mysql client and run in my OSX system prefs. I double checked and `mysql2` is listed in my `LOCAL GEMS` list within the terminal. I can launch it as well. Still getting the same error when typing in `Rails server` from within my rails project folder. Sorry, I am so noob at this. Any alternatives to get around this? Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the mysql2 client and server, here's a tutorial on how to do it using `brew`, a packet manager I personally recommend:

http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2010/02/28/installing-mysql-on-snow-leopard-using-homebrew/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the mysql client and its libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. The problem was mysql, not the mysql gem. I solved it by re-installing mysql using Homebrew:

1. Install Homebrew: [Link](https://brew.sh)
2. Install mysql in terminal: https://gist.github.com/trey/2722782

   ```
    $ brew install mysql
   ```